# Optical drive power settings: Wait longer before spinning down

Tags: livecd, dvd

When running from a live DVD, something highly annoying is:

I click on something. then I hear the DVD drive starting to spin.
Now, I know that I need to wait five seconds until the computer reacts for the next time.

**How can I tell the DVD drive to keep spinning for 20 minutes instead of 1 minute?**

I have already set the reading speed to the minimum constant angular velocity (CAV) setting.

Comment: this won't change that much the amount of time needed to access the data you realize that ?

Comment: The ide-cd driver had an undocumented ioctl CDROMSETSPINDOWN, but that seems to be the only driver that references it, and I'm pretty sure you're not using the ide-cd driver. (The documentation for the driver mentions `/dev/hda` etc - that's with a `h` - and not `/dev/sr0`). The only reference I can find is an unconfirmed SO answer that you can do this with `sdparm`, if you know how to specify the right parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43374896/799204

Comment: If you _can_ use a nice USB instead, that's the way to go. Nowadays a lot of people have access to enough computers & internet, that it's not as important to keep a DVD somewhere as a rescue disc, you can just create a rescue USB. (And some of these computers would need you to have a USB DVD drive in order to even use a rescue disc, so it's good to have a USB available for this anyway).

Comment: @Kiwy Yes, but I do not need to wait it **to spin up again.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by [sourcejedi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/29483/sourcejedi), you can use `sdparm` to tweak the Power Condition page entries.

To see the current values, run `sdparm -p po /dev/sr0` (or whatever your drive is). This will show the current timeouts (`ICT` and `SCT`; the `IDLE` and `STANDBY` flags also need to be set).

To change the values, run

```
sdparm -p po -s ICT=12000 /dev/sr0
sdparm -p po -s SCT=12000 /dev/sr0
```

(this will set both to 20 minutes).

Once you have settings which work for you, you can store them as power-on defaults for the drive with the `-S` option:

```
sdparm -S -p po -s ICT=12000 /dev/sr0
sdparm -S -p po -s SCT=12000 /dev/sr0
```